# Displaying multiple series in the navigator of an HighStock chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to create an HighStock chart containing a navigator component displaying multiple series, being the same series displayed in the main graph. It seems that this feature is not supported in HighStock, as only one single series is allowed. Has anyone faced this problem and managed to find a viable solution/alternative?

Comment: And, if I'm not mistaken, usually the first data series is displayed. Even if you turn all series disabled from the legend block.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Multiple series in navigator are not oficially supported, so only this "hack" which you use display multiply series in navigator. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6fFwM/ This feature is requested in our system here (http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2361925-allow-navigator-to-have-multiple-data-series), so you can vote for it.

```
window.chart.addSeries({
        name : "",
        xAxis: 0,
        yAxis: 1,
        type: "line",
        enableMouseTracking: false,
        data : new_data,
        showInLegend:false
});
```

Comment: Little change in data so users now that there are multiple lines in the navigator http://jsfiddle.net/6fFwM/73/

Answer (score 10):

From Highstock 5 this is now officially supported. You can globally or specifically for each series specify `showInNavigator: true` ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.showInNavigator)). A related option is `navigatorOptions` ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.navigatorOptions)) which will affect the series that have the `showInNavigator` set to `true`.

For example: ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phhqrrfk/3/)):

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        showInNavigator: true // Global value
    }
},

series: [{ // This series has no value set and will use global
    name: 'MSFT',
    data: MSFT
},
{
    name: 'GOOGL',
    showInNavigator: false, // Individual series value
    data: GOOGL
},
{
    name: 'ADBE',
    showInNavigator: true, // Individual series value
    navigatorOptions: { // Specific values that affect the series in the navigator only
        type: 'line',
        color: 'red'
    },
    data: ADBE
}]
```