# How can I fix the navigator issue in highstock when I have more than 1 series in different time intervals?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have the following problem, I have a chart with highstock, with the following issue, if my first serie starts on july 2012 to november 2012 and my second serie starts on july 2013 to September 2013, the navigator only use the first serie, and looks weird like missing data, so how can I say to the navigator what use a complete interval containing both series and not only the first
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying multiple series in the navigator of an HighStock chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604757/displaying-multiple-series-in-the-navigator-of-an-highstock-chart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use chart.addSeries()

```
chart.addSeries({
    name : "",
    xAxis: 0,
    yAxis: 1,
    type: "line",
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    data : your set of data to be shown in navigator,
    showInLegend:false
})
```

this will add a series to navigator.

a similar question is answered [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2361925-allow-navigator-to-have-multiple-data-series)

Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/UaCf7/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also prepare separated serie (concate both series data) during preprocessing, which will be used by navigator.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.series