# multiple pane in highstock has issues with scrollbar

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am trying to have 3 or more panes in `highstock` chart but facing an issue with scrollbar. The scrollbar is in sync with the first chart only and it's not in sync with the rest of the two charts. here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/r1xc67uj/1/).

Can anyone help me point to a right way of doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying multiple series in the navigator of an HighStock chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604757/displaying-multiple-series-in-the-navigator-of-an-highstock-chart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {` with `window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({` so that you have the `chart` object, then add:

```
window.chart.addSeries({
        name : "",
        xAxis: 0,
        yAxis: 3,
        type: "line",
        enableMouseTracking: false,
        data :[your data],
        showInLegend:false
    });
```

yAxis `3` is the yAxis of the navigator. You can add as many series as you want - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r1xc67uj/2/)

Comment: Thanks A lot Raeen!! It seems to be working,I'll make the changes and test it

Comment: You can use the `navigator` option and add the first series yourself. Then use the method in my answer for the rest of the series and it will be OK: http://jsfiddle.net/r1xc67uj/4/

Comment: Thanks A ton... Raeen .Its perfectly working.I have a very large data set ,So it took time to test the implementation suggested by you. I have tested it for thousands of points with three pane it its working awesome. Thanks A Lot!!!